# How to expand a time series in R

Tags: r

**Please note** this is NOT a duplicate of other time series expansion questions. There is no start and end date, its based on the value of the number of days in a month and the months are repeated.

Say I have the following data set:

```
  dates<-c("2019-01-07", "2019-02-07", "2019-03-07", "2019-01-22", "2019-02-25")
  month<-c("Jan", "Feb", "March", "Jan", "Feb")
  no_days_PerMonth <-c(31, 28, 31, 31, 28)
  values<-c(54,89,100, 50, 6)
  (test<-as.data.frame(cbind(dates, no_days_PerMonth, month, values)))

     dates    no_days_PerMonth month values
1 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2 2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
3 2019-03-07               31 March    100
4 2019-01-22               31   Jan     50
5 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6
```

What I would like to do is generate a new data frame that takes the number of days in the month of the `dates` variable and expands the number of rows to match that particular number of days for that month and to map the column `values` to each new row. I want something along the lines of the following:

```
dates     no_days_PerMonth month values new_date
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-01
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-02
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-03
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-04
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-05
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-06
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-07
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-08
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-09
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-10
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    2019-01-11
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    .
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    .
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    .
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54    
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-01-07               31   Jan     54
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-01
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-02
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-03
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-04
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-05
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-06
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-07
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-08
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-09
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    2019-02-10
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    .
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    .
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89    .
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
2019-02-07               28   Feb     89
```

The "..." simply represents the continuation of the data expansion (I didn't want to take the time write it all out). Also, in the example dataset below, the expansion is shown only for the first two dates in the original dataset because I didn't feel like taking the time to write it all out.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. The structure and question are different than the the "duplicate posted"! For one, its not a regular sequence of time series and two there are no start and end dates.

Comment: The same solution from the duplicate still applies; but I agree it is (slightly) different. I've removed the dupe flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` plus `lubridate` solution

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(test)[, .(dates, no_days_PerMonth, month, values, new_date = seq(
    floor_date(as.Date(dates), "month"),
    floor_date(as.Date(dates), "month") %m+% days(as.numeric(as.character(no_days_PerMonth))),
    by = "day")), by = dates]
#        dates      dates no_days_PerMonth month values   new_date
#1: 2019-01-07 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54 2019-01-01
#2: 2019-01-07 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54 2019-01-02
#3: 2019-01-07 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54 2019-01-03
#4: 2019-01-07 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54 2019-01-04
#5: 2019-01-07 2019-01-07               31   Jan     54 2019-01-05
#---
#150: 2019-02-25 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6 2019-02-25
#151: 2019-02-25 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6 2019-02-26
#152: 2019-02-25 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6 2019-02-27
#153: 2019-02-25 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6 2019-02-28
#154: 2019-02-25 2019-02-25               28   Feb      6 2019-03-01
```

Explanation: We use `floor_date` to obtain the first day of the month from `dates`, then we expand `dates` using `seq.Date` from the first day of the month up until the first day of the month from `dates` *plus* `no_days_PerMonth`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I see that it works just fine in my sample data but in my real data, I get the following error: `Error in seq.Date(floor_date(as.Date(dates), "month"), floor_date(as.Date(dates),  : 
  'to' must be of length 1`. Any ideas?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Can you replace `by = dates` with `by = seq_len(nrow(test))` and try again?